# Sharepoint - Create new link in Documents and link to asp.net page

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

[image]

I have an aspx page (c# application), which i have to link to the new link created under documents. How to create a new link and map it to new seperate aspx page Please guide me

Answer (score 0):

The way to add a new link depends on whether you have the publishing features enabled or not.

If you have, you go to site actions / site settings / modify all site settings. Under look and feel, there should be a 'Navigation' link that brings you to a page where you can add a link to your application.

If you don't, you go to site actions / site settings and search for the link 'Quick launch' under look and feel.

Comment: where to place the aspx page and the dll

Comment: There are several options. The easiest is this one: register your assembly in the GAC (you'll need to sign it first) and put your aspx file in the layouts folder. Ideally you'll create a subfolder there. For example: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\12\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyCustomPages\MyPage.aspx. Then your page is available to every site in SharePoint. If you have a site http://intranet.litwareinc.com/ then your page can be found on http://intranet.litwareinc.com/_layouts/MyCustomPages/MyPage.aspx

Comment: Btw: the best way to deploy this would be to create a sharepoint solution package. I'm not going to explain how to create one here, it's well documented on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms413687(v=office.12).aspx